# Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file using Android ndk-build

Tags: android, android-ndk

I get the following error while trying to compile an Android NDK project:

```
ndk-build 
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /home/lambergar/work/APIExample/jni/Android.mk    
/home/lambergar/android/ndk/android-ndk-r5c/build/core/add-application.mk:116: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

The weird thing is, that the 'unknown file' (Android.mk) exists under the path reported as invalid.

Comment: try to build your project with the flag NDK_LOG set to 1: that is $NDK/ndk-build NDK_LOG=1 to see more information about this error...
maybe [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/1c8511da02fa5e3d) helps you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a new build to the project and voila, it works... Don't know what was the problem with the CLI build though.

Answer (score 25):

Same problem (in Windows 7) but the cause is different.

After searching in the Environment parameters, I've found the evil thing named "NDK_PROJECT_PATH" which has value is an invalid path.

Deleted it and things are working again ;)

Comment: This is important! Other suggestions may lead people to add the NDK_PROJECT_PATH environment variable and point it to the NDK directory or something. If this exists, and you try to compile a new project, it will complain because it's looking for files in the NDK_PROJECT_PATH. I just ran into the same stupid issue. This solved it.

Answer (score 19):

In my case the problem was with white spaces in the project path. In such case, change the project path folders and import the project again.

Comment: The old new thing hitting us again and again ;)

Answer (score 8):

Just saw this problem today.
In my case actual problem was spaces inside path to project.

(yes, `ndk-build` will not compile your project if you have spaces inside folder name)

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem. I fixed it by creating a Application.mk in $NDK/apps/ndktestapp with following content:

```
APP_PROJECT_PATH := /cygdrive/c/workspace/MyApp
```

and then calling

```
make APP=ndktestapp
```

from the NDK-Root. Hope that helps.

Comment: For more flexibility, I would recommend `APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(call my-dir)`

Answer (score 3):

Just spent an hour or two trying to figure this one out. Many, many people have had this problem. But as I found out I actually did not have a file name Android.mk it was named Andriod.mk and that was enough to cause me a lot of trouble. Sorry about my original rant but that was the whole problem in the end. I suggest if you have this problem you should check everything until you find something wrong.

This fixed me right up. Thanks guys you put me on the right track anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the env variable `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` to the root of the project you are building. The root of your NDK project will typically contain the `./jni` directory.

```
export NDK_PROJECT_PATH={root_of_project}
```

If your JNI code is in a library, then set `NDK_PROJECT_PATH` to the library project.

Comment: NDK project will typically contain the ./jni directory.

Answer (score 3):

Do not make any **white space** in the Project Directory. If errors come again
then edit the ***build.gradle(Module:app)*** below *buildTypes block* and add those line like below:

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
       ......................
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni/','src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'build/intermediates/ndk/debug/Android.mk'
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is not an accepted answer (because there is no white space in project path), it help me find the problem in my project.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove these directories

```
rm -rf .externalNativeBuild //if exits

rm -rf app/.externalNativeBuild

rm -rf app/.cxx/ //if exits

rm -rf app/build/
```

then rebuild the project.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. I had recently refactored my module name in Android Studio. The old project folder name had been cached in the `.externalNativeBuild` configuration files (which store the args passed into ndk-build)

Comment: No help for me, building without android studio (just ndk-build), although weirdly in my case, I have the exact same .mk files for another project that does work.

Answer (score 1):

as the same as @phavens, i think that only wrong with the word Android.mk and android.mk file, just spent for 5 minutes .. hehe

Comment: Gradle paths seem to be case sensitive, even on Windows! `android.mk != Android.mk`.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the project folder name had a space in it removed the space re imported it to Android Studio and that solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Details of the problem:

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: /jni/Android.mk
...: *** Android NDK: Aborting... . Stop.
Usually this  is not the path of your project, so the reason for this error is that ndk could not find the correct Android.mk file path.
solution:

Add NDK_PROJECT_PATH to "./" in the environment variable, the purpose is to tell the NDK that the jni currently to be compiled is located in the directory where the project is located.

Comment: This was my fix! My `ndk-build NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/xxx/` command line was incorrect [path] where `/xxx/` matches `/xxx/jni/android.mk`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similiar probblems as in this topic. My solution is: firstly check the file exist in the correct path. Secondly, if your path have any whitespace, remove it or relocate your project to a simple path. Then rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Android-NDK and tried "ndk-build". 
I had exactly the same error. Here is how I beat it.

```
bash

export NDK_PROJECT_PATH={root_of_android_ndk}/samples/hello-jni

./ndk-build
```

This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Android.mk file, you give the path where the jni folder loacted...
in your case
ARTOOLKIT_DIR :=/home/lambergar/work/APIExample/

Answer (score 0):

For me, deleted the `.gradle` and `app/.externalNativeBuild` directories and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had space in the path for one of the folders. I struggled for 2-3 hrs understanding the problem and wondering why it said it is not able to find a file in a path which I was able to see. On seeing answers here, I removed space in one of the foldername in the path and voila, it started working.

Answer (score -1):

Gradle Experimental plugein in Android Studio add support for Native project build.