# "Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk"

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

i searched all the net ( i think ) . and what ever it said i tried but with no luck still
not working . 
im test it both  under cygwin and under windows
this is my file/dirs of the project :

```
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\.classpath
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\.project
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\AndroidManifest.xml
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\assets
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\files
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\gen
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\proguard.cfg
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\project.properties
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\res
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\jni
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\JniTestActivity.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\R$attr.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\R$drawable.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\R$layout.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\R$string.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\com\testjni\R.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\bin\classes\jni\Natives.class
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\gen\com
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\gen\com\testjni
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\gen\com\testjni\R.java
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\Android.mk
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\Application.mk
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\include
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\lib.c
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\main.c
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\Makefile
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\testlib
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\testlib.c
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\include\jni_Natives.h
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\native\include\jni_Natives.h_orig
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-hdpi
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-ldpi
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-mdpi
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\layout
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\values
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-ldpi\ic_launcher.png
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\drawable-mdpi\ic_launcher.png
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\layout\main.xml
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\res\values\strings.xml
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src\com
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src\jni
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src\com\testjni
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src\com\testjni\JniTestActivity.java
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest\src\jni\Natives.java
```

and this is my ndk NDK_LOG=1 output :

```
D:\Java_2\workspace_indigo\JniTest>ndk-build NDK_LOG=1
Android NDK: NDK installation path auto-detected: 'D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8'
Android NDK: GNU Make version 3.81 detected
Android NDK: Host OS was auto-detected: windows
Android NDK:  Host operating system detected: windows
Android NDK: Host CPU was auto-detected: x86
Android NDK: HOST_TAG set to windows
Android NDK: Host tools prebuilt directory: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/prebuilt/windows/bin
Android NDK: Host 'echo' tool: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/prebuilt/windows/bin/echo.exe
Android NDK: Host 'awk' tool: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/prebuilt/windows/bin/awk.exe
Android NDK: Host 'awk' test returned: Pass
Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following target architectures and ABIS:
Android NDK:    arm: armeabi armeabi-v7a
Android NDK:    mips: mips
Android NDK:    x86: x86
Android NDK:  This NDK supports the following toolchains and target ABIs:
Android NDK:    arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3:  armeabi armeabi-v7a
Android NDK:    mipsel-linux-android-4.4.3:  mips
Android NDK:    x86-4.4.3:  x86
Android NDK: Found platform root directory: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms
Android NDK: Found supported platforms: android-14 android-3 android-4 android-5 android-8 android-9
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-14 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-14/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-3 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-3/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-3/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-3/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-4 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-4/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-4/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-4/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-5 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-5/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-5/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-5/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-8 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-8/arch-x86
Android NDK: PLATFORM android-9 supports: arm mips x86
Android NDK:   ABI arm sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
Android NDK:   ABI mips sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-9/arch-mips
Android NDK:   ABI x86 sysroot is: D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/platforms/android-9/arch-x86
Android NDK: Found stable platform levels: 14 3 4 5 8 9
Android NDK: Found max platform level: 14
Android NDK: Found project path: .
Android NDK: Ouput path: ./obj
Android NDK: Parsing D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/build/core/default-application.mk
Android NDK:   Found APP_PLATFORM=android-8 in ./project.properties
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk
D:/cpp/Android/android-ndk-r8-windows/android-ndk-r8/build/core/add-application.mk:133: *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

and my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := Hello
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib.c


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

and my Application.mk
APP_PROJECT_PATH := D:/Java_2/workspace_indigo/JniTest
```

simple like it said in the docs , but still doesn't work .. 
what is it why its not working what im missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Your APP\_BUILD\_SCRIPT points to an unknown file using Android ndk-build](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6494567/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, your Android.mk file is located in the wrong place, because it's current location is:

```
native/Android.mk
```

and your build script expects it to be in

```
src/jni/Android.mk
```

You have to change the script or copy/move the file.

Comment: Thanks , how did you spot this ?

Comment: i've just noticed the error message complained about `Android.mk` and used 'search' button to find if it's mentioned anywhere else. fortunately you have included your directory listing =)

Comment: Am also getting this error with android-ndk-r12b, but there are many Android.mk files in subdirs.  Do you have any suggestions on which file I need to copy to ~/jni/Android.mk?

Comment: We don't use `src/jni/...` directory structure. (And we don't work for the tools; we expect them to work for us). How do we make the tools use our directory structure?

Comment: @lenik - Based on the question's output with the directory structure, the original question is not using `jni/` either. They seem to be the same problem and same error message to me. Perhaps I am missing something obvious?