# Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: Android.mk

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I know this question was asked before but I tried all existing solutions and none of them solved the issue.

I am trying to create a simple hello world native app (binary not apk) but I keep getting this error message when I try to compile using "ndk-build"

Android.mk

```cpp
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := main.out
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Application.mk

```cpp
APP_ABI := x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-25
APP_STL := stlport_static
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := Android.mk
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

here is the structure for my folder

```cpp
.
└── jni
    ├── Android.mk
    ├── Application.mk
    └── main.cpp
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android NDK: Your APP\_BUILD\_SCRIPT points to an unknown file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6494567/608639)

Answer (score 0):

In this case setting `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT` shouldn't be necessary since you seem to be using the default name and location.

But let's say your `Android.mk` was named `foo.mk`. The thing about `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT` is that *"The build system always interprets a non-absolute path as relative to the NDK's top-level directory"*.

So you'll probably want to specify an absolute path, but preferably not an entirely hardcoded one since that will complicate things if you move things around on your computer or try to move the project to a different computer.

You can solve this in the following way:

```
MY_APP_DIR := $(call my-dir)
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(MY_APP_DIR)/foo.mk
```

Comment: What file is this added to: `APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(MY_APP_DIR)/foo.mk`?

Comment: @jww: Application.mk

Comment: *"The build system always interprets a non-absolute path as relative to the NDK's top-level directory"* – I believe this is a mistake in the doc. Actually, **APP_BUILD_SCRIPT** is interpreted relative to the **$PWD** (in Windows, **%CD%**). It's true that often we run **ndk-build** from the directory above **jni**, but there is no such ***rule***. E.g. all would work well for the TS, if they only run **ndk-build -C jni**.